# C# ValueType Initialization to 0

Tags: c#, initialization, value-type

I'm reading **'Effective C#, By Bill Wagner'** and in Item 12 (Chapter 2, **Resource Management**) he speaks about **Member Initializers** and Assignment Statements.

He **recommends** using **initializers** to avoid uninitialized variables in custom types and not initialize variables in each constructor you define.

So it says three **cases when is better not to initialize** Type variables at the declaration, **one** of them **is**:

*"when you are initializing the **object to 0 or null**"*:

```
MyValType myVal1; // initialized to 0
MyValType myVal2 = new MyValType(); // also 0
```

He **recommends** to use the **case 1**, for not being superfluous.

I'm still a newbie but, as I know, `myVal1` will be `null` and `myVal2` should be an instantiated object with the corresponding properties, so

can someone explain to me what does this mean, or maybe if I missunderstood this concept?

Comment: Valuetypes aren´t initialized to `null`, but to their default-value (e.g. zero for int).

Comment: "myVal2 should be an instantiated object with the corresponding properties" That would be true for a _reference type_, not for a value type, which gets initialised with default(yourtype).

Comment: Value types are always initialized with a value. Reference types are initialized to `null`.

Comment: @oerkelens so this applies for `struct` ?